# e-mail servers use wrong hostname

Tags: bug, status-completed, email

Currently, the e-mail servers trying to deliver mail from stackexchange to my address appear to sit behind `69.59.196.221`:

> Dec 18 21:33:56 avalon postfix/smtpd[1132]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[69.59.196.221]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [69.59.196.221]; from=<do-not-reply@stackexchange.com> to=<myemailaddress@example.org> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx-out.stackexchange.com>

As you can see, my mail server rejects this e-mail, since it cannot find the IP address `69.59.196.221` in the records for `mx-out.stackexchange.com`, where it should be in every sane set-up (don’t claim to be A when A claims not to know you).

The actual records as available in the DNS at the moment:

```
$ dig -x 69.59.196.221 PTR +short
peak-colo-196-221.peak.org.
$ dig mx-out.stackexchange.com +short
72.51.63.225
64.34.119.225
```

Is it possible to fix this such that `69.59.196.221` is listed as one of the hostnames for `mx-out.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: I opened this with the intention of VtC as "Off topic" :P.

Comment: Well there should only be a few mail servers for which MSO is on-topic, so I thought I could save the ‘SE’ in front of ‘e-mail servers’ :-)

Comment: I'm on it, standby.

Comment: @Claudius MSO receives multiple questions every day that ought to be posted on SO or SF or some other site, but weren't due to their OPs being brand-new, utterly confused or question-banned on the appropriate site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an oversight on our part, we did not add it to the DNS record when we failed over to Oregon during ***SUPERSTORM SANDY***.  I have pushed the proper IPs into the A record and it should sync over the next hour or so.

```
for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do host mx-out.stackexchange.com ns$i.serverfault.com; done
Using domain server:
Name: ns1.serverfault.com
Address: 64.34.119.33#53
Aliases:

mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 64.34.119.225
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 72.51.63.225
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.221
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.222
Using domain server:
Name: ns2.serverfault.com
Address: 64.34.119.34#53
Aliases:

mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 64.34.119.225
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 72.51.63.225
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.221
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.222
Using domain server:
Name: ns3.serverfault.com
Address: 69.59.196.217#53
Aliases:

mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 64.34.119.225
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.221
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.222
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 72.51.63.225
Using domain server:
Name: ns4.serverfault.com
Address: 69.59.196.122#53
Aliases:

mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.221
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 69.59.196.222
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 64.34.119.225
mx-out.stackexchange.com has address 72.51.63.225
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you very much for the quick response. If I remember correctly, it would probably also be a good idea if the PTR records for these IPs (currently `peak-colo-196-221.peak.org.` for `69.59.196.221` and correspondingly for `.222`) would again resolve to/include said IPs. This is done for `72.51.63.225` and `64.34.119.225` already (these resolve to `mx-out.stackexchange.com`)

Comment: This is something that will have to wait until we get more IP addresses at PEAK.  .221 and .222 are our nat overload addresses and I don't want to explicitly give them a PTR.

Comment: This is not fixed.

`Feb  7 16:33:11 eclipse postfix/smtpd[22889]: connect from unknown[69.59.196.222]
Feb  7 16:33:12 eclipse postfix/smtpd[22889]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[69.59.196.222]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [69.59.196.222]; from=<do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com> to=<me@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx-out.stackexchange.com>
Feb  7 16:33:12 eclipse postfix/smtpd[22889]: disconnect from unknown[69.59.196.222]`

Comment: To be clear, what Milos is complaining about is the missing PTR records, not the A records (these are good). And if *that*'s the reason I haven't received the newsletter recently, then… please do get those extra IPs asap.

Comment: We'll be moving back to New York very soon, which should resolve this issue for those with PTR-checking mailservers.